# Vue Vuex with Typescript Vuex object not known type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I am having issues trying to get Vuex with Typescript working. I did an example without typescript which worked just fine as shown first below. I am creating a Vuex module and then adding it as shown below

src -> store -> index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import robotsModule from './modules/products';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    products: productsModule
  },
});
```

src -> store -> modules -> products.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    products: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    addProduct(state, product) {
      state.products.push(product);
    },
    updateProduct(state, products) {
      state.parts = products;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    getProducts({ commit }) {
      axios
        .get('/api/products')
        .then(result => commit('updateProduct', result.data))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  },
};
```

Now when I want to use typescript it keeps complaining that

> "Binding element 'commit' implicitly has an 'any' type."

As you can see I have currently specified the state as **any** which also seems wrong.
How do I make this work nicely with typescript?

src -> store -> modules -> products.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Product } from '@/models/product';

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    products: new Array<Product>(),
  },
  mutations: {
    updateProducts(state: any, products: Product[]) {
      state.products = products;
    },
    addProduct(state: any, product: Product) {
      state.products.push(product);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    getProducts({ commit }) {
      axios
        .get('/api/products')
        .then(result => commit('updateProducts', result.data))
        .catch(console.error);
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an example online which showed that I needed to have the commit as a function

```
getProducts({ commit }: { commit: Function }) {
```

full file here

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { Product } from '@/models/product';
import State from '@/models/state';

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    items: new Array<Product>(),
  } as State,
  mutations: {
    updateProducts(state: State, products: Product[]) {
      state.items = products;
    },
    addProduct(state: State, product: Product) {
      state.items.push(product);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    getProducts({ commit }: { commit: Function }) {
      axios
        .get('/api/products')
        .then(result => {
          commit('updateProducts', result.data);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    },
  },
};
```

Also create a State class that I could then say is my state object

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Product } from '@/models/product';

export default class State extends Vue {
  items: Product[] = new Array<Product>();
}
```

Update 15-03-2021 - A work colleague of mine said he now used https://www.npmjs.com/package/direct-vuex which makes it easier!

Answer (score 2):

Building upon Andrew's answer - you can introduce a couple of interfaces to tidy up the code a little:

```
export interface CommitFunction {
    commit: Commit;
}

export interface CommitStateFunction<T> extends CommitFunction {
    state: T;
}
```

So then your action would look like:

```
actions: {
    getProducts({ commit }: CommitFunction) { /* logic here */ },
    updateProducts({ commit, state }: CommitStateFunction<State>) { /* logic here */ }
}
```

Comment: You need to `import { Commit } from 'vuex'` to avoid an error on the commit type declaration